# STGenericIntentDateRange undefined in Xcode 7 Beta

Tags: ios, xcode, beta, xcode7

I get the following message in the console when running my app after upgrading to the latest Xcode 7 Beta:

```
objc[51750]: Class STGenericIntentDateRange is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SiriTasks.framework/SiriTasks and /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/PhotosUI.framework/PhotosUI. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I can't find any mention of STGenericIntentDateRange in Apple's documentation or anywhere online. It doesn't appear to be affecting my app and there is no associated warning when building - the message is simply logged.

I'm guessing this is just a beta conflict issue dealing with some rarely used date functionality but I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this or knows a fix?

Comment: My app uses PhotosUI and gets exactly the same message - presumably it's a private class and the issue will be resolved in a future beta release.

Comment: I see the same message, I'm guessing nothing to worry about